# count() "where" statement in Laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am interested in displaying quick counts of email stats in my application, but I'm getting hung up on finding an efficient way to generate the counts. I am hoping to just use the eloquent relationship with some sort of "count where" statement inside of blade.

Getting the total count works as it should:

```
{{count($emails->mandrillemails)}}
```

but is something like this possible?:

```
{{count($emails->mandrillemails->msg_state == 'bounced')}}
{{count($emails->mandrillemails->msg_state == 'open')}}
```

Here is my block of code with the @if and @foreach statements:

```
     @if(count($sentEmails) > 0)
      @foreach ($sentEmails as $emails)
       <tr>
        <td>
          @if(count($emails->mandrillemails) > 0)
             <p><span class="badge"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> {{count($emails->mandrillemails)}}</span> <span class="badge"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> {{count($emails->mandrillemails->msg_state == 'bounced')}}</span></p>
          @endif
        </td>
      </tr>
```

When I attempt this, I get an undefined property error on "msg_state"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count a relationship like this:

```
$emails->mandrillemails()->whereMsgState('bounced')->count();
```

Since you're `@foreach`ing things, you may want to eager load this data. This is a little more complex when you're doing counts on the relationship - see http://laravel.io/forum/05-03-2014-eloquent-get-count-relation and http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/ for some possible techniques to eager-load the count value instead of the whole list of related items.

Answer (score 0):

`$emails->mandrillemails()->whereMsgState('bounced')->count()` should work.